# pynput custom autokey script isn't working when following video guide

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pynput

I wanted to create a hotkey but decided to "challenge" myself by using Python instead of AHK.

I wanted the phrase `Scheiße!` printed out whenever I pressed the key combination Ctrl+Alt+P(or p)

I referred to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_dfv5DLCGI) video and wrote the following script:

```
from pynput import keyboard

COMBINATIONS = [
{keyboard.Key.ctrl, keyboard.Key.alt, keyboard.KeyCode(char='p')}, # Detects ctrl+alt+p
{keyboard.Key.ctrl, keyboard.Key.alt, keyboard.KeyCode(char='P')} # Detects ctrl+alt+P
]

current = set()

def execute():
 print ("Scheiße!") # When the above combo is pressed, the word "Scheiße!" is printed

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]): # Checks if pressed key is in any combinations
        current.add(key) # If it is, then it's added to the current key set
        if any(all (k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS): # Checks if every key of the combination has been pressed
                execute() # If all checks pass, execute is called
def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]): # Checks if a key released is in any of the combinations
        current.remove(key) # If it is, then it's remove from the current key set if applicable

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

When I execute the script, the following error(s) occurs:

```
    ================== RESTART: C:\Users\IMSOASIAN\Desktop\Scheiße!.py =================
Unhandled exception in listener callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IMSOASIAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 211, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\IMSOASIAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 287, in _process
    self.on_release(key)
  File "C:\Users\IMSOASIAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 127, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:
  File "C:\Users\IMSOASIAN\Desktop\Scheiße!.py", line 20, in on_release
    current.remove(key) # If it is, then it's remove from the current key set if applicable
KeyError: 'p'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IMSOASIAN\Desktop\Scheiße!.py", line 23, in <module>
    listener.join()
  File "C:\Users\IMSOASIAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 259, in join
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
  File "C:\Users\IMSOASIAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 702, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\IMSOASIAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 211, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\IMSOASIAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 287, in _process
    self.on_release(key)
  File "C:\Users\IMSOASIAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 127, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:
  File "C:\Users\IMSOASIAN\Desktop\Scheiße!.py", line 20, in on_release
    current.remove(key) # If it is, then it's remove from the current key set if applicable
KeyError: 'p'
```

I've tried various troubleshooting steps such as removing the German characters, replacing 'p' and 'alt' with other keys, but the only thing that does is change the output.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the information you provided, I tested the code in the video in VS Code, and it can be run in VS Code:

[image]

Please use the code:

```
COMBINATIONS = [
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='p')}, # Detects ctrl+alt+p
    {keyboard.Key.shift, keyboard.KeyCode(char='P')} # Detects ctrl+alt+P
]
```

In addition, please reload VS Code to make it recognize the installed modules, and try to run it several times in VS Code.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to activate the hotkey out of the command line?

Comment: @IMSOASIAN -How to understand "out of the command line"?

Comment: As in, to work in any application and not the application I launched it from. It only works in the terminal I launch it from.

Comment: Yeah, but it'll be outputed INSIDE vs code. I want it to be outputted in any text field in any application.

Comment: @IMSOASIAN  -After modifying the code, I clicked the run button in VS Code, and then clicked "Shift" and entered "p" in the internal terminal of VS Code. The result was output in this terminal, and then I opened the system 'cmd' terminal and clicked " Shift" and input "p", the result is output in the VS Code terminal.

Comment: @IMSOASIAN  -But this file is run in VS Code, and we executed the run command in this terminal of VS Code.

Comment: I can unfortunately not create a new thread for two more days, but I just wanna say this happens when I run it in the cmd terminal, Powershell, Python shell, etc. I just wanna be able to insert a word whenever I'm typing something. Sorry about that.

Comment: @IMSOASIAN  -In my test, it can receive the input 'p' or 'keep' (click Shift) from ‘cmd’ and ‘powershell’ from outside VS Code, but its output will be displayed in the terminal where we execute the command. You could enter any word you want, and the result will only be output when you enter the 'p'.

Comment: @IMSOASIAN -Has the problem in this thread been resolved?

Comment: Yes, but a new problem was introduced.